# Adding values from a controller to a dropdown Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

In my Controller I have

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCounties", method = {RequestMethod.GET},produces=MediaType.Application_JSON_VALUE)
public @Responcebody List<Counties>(@RequestParam String province){

    List<Counties> county = this.xService.getCounties(county);
    return county;
}
```

This method send the province chosen in the form down to the repository and join on the counties within that province.

In my dropdown on the form how do I return these values into the dropdown.

I currently have

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:select path="cdGcd" class="textbox" onclick="getCounty()">  
            <form:option value="-" label="Please Select"/>
            <form:options path="county" items='${county}' itemValue = "countycode" itemLabel="countydescription"/>
        </form:select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not return `List` directly form controller.
For passing data from controller to JSP you need to add data in `Model` and return respective JSP page.

So you need to change your method to,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCounties", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String getCountries(@RequestParam String province, Model model){
    List<Counties> county = this.xService.getCounties(county);
    model.addAttribute("county",county);
    return "jsp page";
}
```

If you want to achieve this using AJAX then,you need to return JsonObject from controller.

Comment: I am passing the JsonObject through, but how do I call it from the AJAX function up to the dropdown?

Comment: I am passing the JsonObject through, but how do I call it from the AJAX function up to the dropdown?

Comment: @user3399863 you need to make ajax call to controller and return JsonObject and get respective JsonObject in ajax response and append response data with select.
For more help update your question with whatever you are tried upto so i can give proper implementation